# Change Spring context for Specific bean

Tags: spring, annotations, javabeans

If I have a class which sets the value using the @Value annotation

```
class myClass{
    @Value(${myservice})
    public MyService _myService;
}
```

bean configuration looks somewhat like this:

```
<bean id="myservice" class="tomy.MyService"></bean>    //in Spring context

<bean id="myClass" class="tomy.myClass"></bean>
```

say someone comes along and wants myClass to use myService2 (shares common super class with 'myservice') without touching the java class - is it possible to change the output / "value" of ${myservice}

ie.

```
<bean id="myClass" class="tomy.myClass">
    <property name="myservice" ref="myOtherService" />     //this of course doesn't work as it looks for the setter method of myService
</bean>
```

so that

```
class myClass{
        @Value(${myservice})
        public MyService _myService;
    }
```

_myService should now store an instance of myOtherService and not myService

**Edit:**

Perhaps a better way to describe it would be... if it is possible to override Autowired from xml without touching the java bean and without better methods?

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible without touching the java class because _myService is of type MyService so it cannot point to an instance of type MyService2. You must change the java class so _myService will be of the common super class type.

Comment: but if they both extend from the same class then they are of the same type are they not?

Comment: They both extend the type of the super class but are not the same type, but the problem is that the variable _myService is declare as MyService so it can only refer to objects of type MyService (meaning objects of type MyService or of types that extend MyService), and an object of type MyService2 is not of type MyService. `public abstract class Animal {}`

Comment: `class Animal {}` `class Cat extends Animal {}` `class Dog extends Animal {}` `Animal c = new Cat();//ok` `Animal d = new Dog();//ok` `Cat c2 = new Dog();//not ok`

Answer (score 1):

Some where you have to make your container to understand that you want to inject your `MyService2` bean in `MyClass` bean. So it has to be in your xml configuration or `MyClass` class.

For these type of thing, usually [Service Locator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) is heavily used.

[Here](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) you find the legendary blog post on [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) by [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com), discussing the pros and cons of Service locator and various kinds of Dependency injections.

See Also:

- [ServiceLocatorFactoryBean in Spring with example](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ServiceLocatorFactoryBean.html)